# Require sql logic so that a user can work on 8 products per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have excel sheet in which I have unique products. A user can only work on 8 products per date. **FIRST 8 products are defined randomly, no logic for it.** 
Currently, its done manually by a team member who adds date to the date column. I want to write logic in SQL server to assign dates to users so that first 8 products are due on current date for the user and then next 8 or less products are due next day

When the user changes then repeat the above logic. Screenshot below for reference.

First data below is the current data and second data is the expected result

**Current Data**

```
Product  USER   Due DATE       
123       A      -     
234       A      -     
456       A      -     
678       A      -     
345       A      -     
346       A      -     
235       A      -     
754       A      -     
125       A      -     
782       A      -     
235       A      -     
564       A      -     
452       A      -     
176       A      -     
982       A      -     
450       A      -     
127       A      -     
167       B      -     
357       B      -     
137       B      -     
125       B      -     
326       B      -
```

**Expected results**

```
Product  USER   Due DATE       
123       A     12/19/2019     
234       A     12/19/2019     
456       A     12/19/2019     
678       A     12/19/2019     
345       A     12/19/2019     
346       A     12/19/2019     
235       A     12/19/2019     
754       A     12/19/2019     
125       A     12/20/2019     
782       A     12/20/2019     
235       A     12/20/2019     
564       A     12/20/2019     
452       A     12/20/2019     
176       A     12/20/2019     
982       A     12/20/2019     
450       A     12/20/2019     
127       A     12/21/2019     
167       B     12/19/2019     
357       B     12/19/2019     
137       B     12/19/2019     
125       B     12/19/2019     
326       B     12/19/2019
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first 8 products" in a relational database.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  "First" is only defined if a column has the ordering information.

Comment: @seanlange - Here's the new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage ROW_NUMBER for this. But as pointed out the order will be random, and not even the same each time you run this. This using a trick with integer division that it will always return an integer.

```
declare @Product table
(
    Product int
    , MyUser char(1)
)

insert @Product values
('123', 'A')     
, ('234', 'A')     
, ('456', 'A')     
, ('678', 'A')     
, ('345', 'A')     
, ('346', 'A')     
, ('235', 'A')     
, ('754', 'A')     
, ('125', 'A')     
, ('782', 'A')     
, ('235', 'A')     
, ('564', 'A')     
, ('452', 'A')     
, ('176', 'A')     
, ('982', 'A')     
, ('450', 'A')     
, ('127', 'A')     
, ('167', 'B')     
, ('357', 'B')     
, ('137', 'B')     
, ('125', 'B')     
, ('326', 'B')   

select p.Product
    , p.MyUser
    , DueDate = convert(date, DATEADD(day, (ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by p.MyUser order by (select null)) - 1) / 8, getdate())) 
from @Product p
order by MyUser
```

Comment: The order will not be *random*.  It will be *indeterminate*.  `random` is actually quite well-defined and hard to achieve in practice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is true. But I doubt the OP really means random in this case. I think they mean the order doesn't really matter. Just pick any 8 for each group.

Comment: @SeanLange - Thank you so much for your help. It looks great. thanks